# Show that the sum of the products in pairs of the number 1,2,3...p-1 is divisible by p, where p is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p ≥ 5$ is prime, show that the sum of the products in pairs of the
numbers $1, 2, . . . , p−1$ is divisble by p. We do not count $1×1$, and
$1 × 2$ precludes $2 × 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

If the sum of of the products in pairs $=P,$

as $(a+b+c+\cdots)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+\cdots)+2(ab+bc+ca+\cdots)$

$$2P=(\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}r)^2-\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}(r^2)$$

$$=\left(\dfrac{p(p-1)}2\right)^2-\dfrac{(p-1)p\{2(p-1)+1\}}6$$

As prime $p\ge5,(p,6)=(p,2)=1$  so $\dfrac{p-1}2$ and $\dfrac{(p-1)(2p-1)}6$ are integers

Do we really need $p$ to be a prime, will $(p,6)=1$ not suffice?

Comment: This actually follows from Newton's Identities.

Comment: Thats pertty clever! $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{p-1}\sum\limits_{r'=1}^{p-1}rr' = \left(\sum\limits_{r=1}^{p-1}r\right)\left(\sum\limits_{r'=1}^{p-1}r'\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$1,2,\ldots,p-1$ are the $p-1$ roots of the polynomial $x^{p-1}-1$ modulo $p$. By [Vieta's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the mentioned sum is congruent (modulo $p$) to the coefficient of $x^{p-3}$ in $x^{p-1}-1$, which is $0$.
Note that this relies on the fact that $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field.